# What's wrong with my Joomla conditional module positions?

Tags: php, html, joomla

Below is my if conditions for how to display the structure depending on if a module is in the 'left' position or 'right' position or if a module is in both the 'left' and 'right'.

The conditions for if a module is in the 'left' position or 'right' position works. But if I have a module in both the 'left' and 'right' positions, only the module in the 'left' position appears, while the module in the 'right' position is not displayed.

Can someone please help me with what the problem is?

```
<?php if($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
<!-- Content Region with Left Column: Start -->
<div class="contentholder onecol">

    <div class="contentcol colleft">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentbody">
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Content Region with Left Column: End -->

<?php elseif($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
<!-- Content Region with Right Column: Start -->
<div class="contentholder onecol">

    <div class="contentbody">
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentcol colleft">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Content Region with Right Column: End -->

<?php elseif(($this->countModules('left')) && ($this->countModules('right'))) : ?>
<!-- Content Region with Left & Right Column: Start -->
<div class="contentholder twocol">

    <div class="contentcol colleft">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="xhtml" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentbody">
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentcol colleft">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="xhtml" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Content Region with Left & Right Column: End -->

<?php else : ?>
<!-- Content Region with No Columns: Start -->
<div class="contentholder">

    <div class="contentbody">
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Content Region with No Columns: End -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the problem was the order of my conditions. The condition:

```
<?php elseif(($this->countModules('left')) && ($this->countModules('right'))) : ?>
```

should come first instead of third.

It seems as though the reason is because a 'left' module in the original first condition is met, so the if statement terminates there. So by adding the 'left' && 'right' condition to the top, if it isn't met, then the code moves on to see if there is only a 'left' module or 'right' module.

Comment: I found this link, which is also helpful: http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_way_modules_are_displayed